# Changing the contents of a web page with respect to system time

Tags: javascript, html

Consider an HTML page. I want to display a group of images in that page with a timer. When the timer ends, a new list of images should appear with a new timer.

For 1 hour the group A images should appear on the page and the 2nd hour Group B images should appear. After 2 hours, the group A should be displayed. So on and so forth.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the technologies you are using to achieve this? jQuery? PHP? I'm going to assume you are using some Javascript due to the 'timer' being required

Comment: java script, HTML/5 ,jsp servlets      ......no php

Comment: To be more clear i want to make a food order page in which some items should only be displayed for a limited period of time. When the time ends new food items should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

In terms of pseudo code the way you would achieve this on the front end would be something like the following:

```
(In AngularJs)
    getData.then(function(data){

    var updateData = function() {
        // update view data here
    }
    // you could set the '500' here to be an hour - but that is poor design
    $timeout(updateData, 500);
})
```

In practice, the user isn't going to be sat there for an hour waiting for the page to update, so you'd want the 'timer' to be set on the server side. for a full implementation I'd advise you look into Websockets + a front end library such as Angular or React